# How can I turn on IPCOMP for a socket?

Tags: linux, tcp

For reasons I can't go into, our system uses a very small MTU (128 bytes).  These embedded devices are on a completely separate network so no internet access or interaction with other devices.

Obviously, TCP takes up 66 bytes per packet leaving not very much for payload.

After some googling, I came across IPCOMP which looks like it may help in reducing the amount of traffic on the network.

My question is how can I enable this?  Is there a setsockopt, or do I need a special driver?

The only example I've seen is:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_COMP)
```

but this means I need to create the IP/TCP/payload manually.

Anyone have experience with this.

EDIT: Perhaps a better method would be to enable cslip or ppp on this connection.  I can find tutorials on enabling PPP on a serial port (for dial-up modem), but nothing on enabling PPP on ethernet.
I've seen articles on PPPoE, but this seems to add MORE to the payload rather than reducing it.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'm curious, is the IP MTU 128, or is that the Ethernet MTU?

Comment: The Ethernet MTU is 128.

Comment: I believe you can do this using `ip xfrm state` and `ip xfrm policy`, but I have yet to attempt it. OpenBSD uses a sysctl flag, but in Linux I believe IPSec has to be used or xfrm has to be used directly.

Comment: any more details? all devices are running linux? and TCP is really necessary for the interconnection between the devices?

Comment: TCP and IP both have minimum header sizes of 20 so you don't need to have more than 40 bytes of overhead.  Also, you can _fragment_ larger TCP/IP packets so that each piece has an IP header (meaning only 20 bytes of overhead per network packet) with only the first containing the TCP overhead.  Of course, that requires fragment/reassembly logic (which is required by the spec but sometimes omitted by embedded systems) and has issues in the face of packet loss.  With this, you have have 88 and 108 payload bytes for the first and additional network packets, respectively.

Comment: What OS are you using? I think it will be not very usefull. In general IPComp used in IPSEC context and its creators adviced against it. IPComp header will add you 4 bytes to the IP payload. Also you should consider nature of your payloads (length, compressible?). If your system supports IPComp than probably IP fragmentation is also supported and in my opinion is a better choice.

Comment: do you really need tcp? what are your requirements? maybe it's easier to use udp or a custom protocol via raw socket.

Answer (score 3):

I've played around with IP xfrm in the past but I've never tried the comp option.  If you want all outgoing traffic compressed, something like this would work.

```
ip xfrm policy add dev eth0 dir out tmpl proto comp
```